# Can Google index page that is login-required and redirects to Login page?

Tags: seo, redirects, googlebot, authentication

I have one link that is login-required `http://example.com/secret` If user access the page without authentication it will be redirected to `http://example.com/login` page.

My question is can Google bot index the `/secret` link? (I don't want it to be displayed on the Search results).

I'm confused because as this [link](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/301-redirects) it said:

> It will show the source page in search results if it's temporary redirect (HTTP code 302)

and this [link](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/robots/intro) it said:

> If you want to block your page from search results, use another method such as password protection

while `/secret` is also both password protection page and redirect source page. I'm not sure it will be indexed or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an appropriate use of the redirect mechanism. The proper way to handle this is to serve a 401 (Not Authorized) header and include your login form in the response.

> while /secret is also both password protection page and redirect source page. I'm not sure it will be indexed or not.

If `/secret` is password protected at the server level and is only reachable by logged in users then it doesn't get indexed and Googlebot never gets redirected.

If `/secret'` is not password protected at the server level, Googlebot will have the same experience as an un-authenticated user, so it will be redirected to `/login` via whichever temporary redirect you choose. This doesn't solve your index problem. Google's indexing pipeline is going to consider ***any*** temporary redirect as a ***weak*** signal that the target should be canonical.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
Can I understand the page is password-protected at the server level is only when it returns 401, otherwise if it redirects to Login page it's not password protected at server level? 
Currently the `/secret` is redirected to `/login` with 302 code. And I see it's normal behavior as gmail ( `https://mail.google.com/mail/u`) or facebook (`https://www.facebook.com/friends`)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question here.